# How do I add links to certain code lines of code repro files in VSO/TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I would like to create Issues / Work items / code Review with comments to certain lines of code that directly link to the file and version.
did I miss that feature? or would it be a case for UserVoice* asking for that feature?

(* for which I would not qualify obviously unless MSDN subscriber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for you to add comments to specific code blocks or links.

In the **Comments** section, select the changed file. Then in the comparison view, right-click in the specific code block and select **Add Comment**.

[image]

Then you will see that the code line information is included in the comments:
[image]

Comment: thank you. exactly what I meant. it seems this function is not know very well on other places. <br> Is this function only available in code reviews? does it has a certain name to search further?

Comment: may I add the question: is it correct I can not see these comments within VSO? on first sight it only seems to work for me inside VS connected to VSO.

Comment: now that I knew what to look for, I found this nice video explaining the feature! http://media.ch9.ms/ch9/1640/b11f8b3b-fc56-4a66-884a-8bb45cc81640/UsingCodeReviewtoImproveQuality.webm